# Why is Application_UnhandledException not triggered for an exception within an Async Function?

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, async-await, caliburn.micro

I have an async member that is called via Caliburn.Micro conventions and throws exceptions. When this member is an 'Async Sub' the exception is handled in the Application_UnhandledException method. When I change it to an 'Async Function' (which just returns a Task), the exception is no longer handled by the Application_UnhandledException method. The application does not crash and the exception just seems to be swallowed without a trace.

**Button Bound via Caliburn.Micro Conventions** - Click event is bound to a method with the same name on the DataContext.

```
<Button x:Name="MyMember" Content="My Button" />
```

**Async Sub Variant** - Application_UnhandledException is Raised

```
Public Async Sub MyMember()
```

**Async Function Variant** - Exception Swallowed

```
Public Async Function MyMember() As System.Threading.Tasks.Task
```

The [documentation for Application_UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.unhandledexception%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) states that it will be raised

> ...for each thrown exception that is unhandled by application code.

Either this is not truly the case or there is some application code further up in the call stack that is handling the exception - possibly within Caliburn.Micro.

There seems to be something similar in [this example](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/f434ddc7-351f-43c5-9535-0eab2048042a/applicationunhandledexception-can-not-capture-the-event?forum=winappswithcsharp) - albeit in C#.

Can anyone explain this behavior? Having exceptions being swallowed like this is a big worry.

**Update:**
I was not able to apply this information but it may be relevant. [You can use Coroutine.Completed event to get your exception.](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/discussions/462124)

**Update 2:**
Valeriu Caraulean addresses the question of whether to use an async void or async Task with Caliburn.Micro [here](http://caraulean.com/blog/2013/07/15/using-caliburn-micro-with-async-await/). He references Stephen's article [Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) where he provides the following guidance.

> ...you should prefer async Task to async void. Async Task methods
>   enable easier error-handling, composability and testability. The
>   exception to this guideline is asynchronous event handlers, which must
>   return void. This exception includes methods that are logically event
>   handlers even if they’re not literally event handlers (for example,
>   ICommand.Execute implementations).

**Update 3:**
I posted a [related question](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/discussions/474905) in the Caliburn.Micro forums.

Comment: Please post the code where this occurs. Are you using the latest version of Caliburn.Micro? v1.5 added support for Tasks and `async/await`. Does the behavior occure in an action method?

Comment: I have added the relevant code excepts. It is not much more than method signatures though.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am using Caliburn.Micro 1.5.1.0 which should have axync/await support. And yes, the MyMember member in the example above is an action method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "call stack" loses a lot of its meaning when you start working with `Async`. Here's what's actually going on:

- `Async Function` methods return a `Task` or `Task<T>`, and any exceptions thrown from that method is placed on the returned task.
- `Async Sub` methods do not have a `Task` on which to place exceptions, so any exceptions thrown from that methods is re-raised on the `SynchronizationContext` that was current at the beginning of the `Async Sub` method.

So, what that means is that `Async Function` exceptions are ignored, unless you observe them (e.g., `Await` the task or read its `Exception` property). When the task is garbage collected, unobserved exceptions are passed to `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException`, but this event is raised *outside* of a request or application context (so there isn't much you can do in response).

On the other hand, `Async Sub` exceptions are re-raised on the `SynchronizationContext` that represents the request context, and that's why they're passed to `Application.UnhandledException`.

Ideally, Caliburn.Micro should understand `Task` handlers. If they don't, then you'll need to contact that team for the best solution. The problem with just using `Async Sub` is that it will continue executing later when the calling code believes it has already completed; this may or may not cause problems - it totally depends on Caliburn.Micro. With `Async Function` at least you are informing the calling code that there's an operation in progress (by returning a `Task`), but whether that task is awaited (and whether its exception is observed) is again entirely up to Caliburn.Micro.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. So Caliburn.Micro is probably using some mechanism such as reflection to locate a method based on its conventions and then executes it. It does not appear to be making a distinction between non-awaitable and awaitable members (those that return a task). If it were to recognize that a method that it is executing is awaitable and actually await it then I would not have any problems. Does this sound right to you? Do I have any options which would not involve changes to the Caliburn.Micro code base other than being disciplined about using Async Subs with Caliburn.Micro?

Comment: That does sound correct. Most likely, Caliburn.Micro is just ignoring the return value instead of treating a `Task` as an asynchronous operation. I definitely would contact the Caliburn team about how you're using it; at this point, a lot of frameworks are in the process of adding support for `async` and specific use cases help. It *is* possible to either block on `async` code or run a kind of nested loop with `AsyncContext` from my AsyncEx library. But both of those approaches are hacks, you lose all benefit of `async`, and the don't work in every situation.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. With the insight that you provided, I was able to perform more targeted searches and coincidentally ended up on your Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming article.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If an exception is thrown in a task the task will be faulted. You can determine this by getting the `Task.IsFaulted` property. If this property is true the `Task.Exception` property will contain an `AggregateException` that combines the exceptions that was unhandled by the task.

The easiest way to handle exceptions in a task is to await the task. The unhandled exception will by the magic of async and await reappear on the thread that awaits the task.

If your task is a "fire-and-forget" task there is no way to handle any unhandled exceptions because you cannot inspect or await the task. In that case you should make sure that your task does not have any unhandled exceptions by catching the exceptions in the task.

You can also handle the [`TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) event. This is somewhat similar to the `Application_UnhandledException` event except it is for tasks.

Comment: That sounds like exactly the sort of thing that I was hoping for. Unfortunately, it is not supported in partial-trust applications.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception(v=vs.95).aspx
When I tried wiring up the event, I got the following exception at runtime.
Attempt by security transparent method 'Midwinter.ReasonableBasis.Client.App..ctor()' to access security critical method 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.add_UnobservedTaskException(System.EventHandler`1<System.Threading.Tasks.UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs>)' failed.

Answer (score -1):

Tasks swallow exceptions unless you wait on them (e.g., C# `await` keyword).  If I recall correctly, it is possible to retrieve any exceptions thrown by a Task after the fact.  This is why warnings are often issued in Visual Studio (at least, in C#) when tasks aren't waited on.

Comment: It sounds then like it is the code that calls my method which is not awaiting it. For the Async Sub this would not be possible so I suppose exceptions here are treated as unhandled and trigger the Application_UnhandledException method. For the Async Function, it is assumed that the caller should await with the exception being swallowed if this is not the case. Can you suggest some means of preventing the exceptions from being swallowed?

Comment: You can store the Task and reference it later to see if any exceptions have been thrown.